# GCC - fatal error in standard libs including

Tags: c++, c, gcc, glibc, archlinux

I'm compiling a code that includes some standard libs as new, cmath and so ...
but the gcc is not able to include them.

I used the python3.2 distutils for building that.

It gives me this error: `gcc fatal error: cmath: No such file or directory`. I googled a bit and there is maybe that my gcc configuration is not good and it must be reinstalled.

I have tried to reinstall glibc and gcc and all its dependencies on my archlinux pc: `sudo pacman -S --recursive glibc gcc` but nothing has changed.

What could the problem be?

Comment: When building C++ program, you should use `g++` and not `gcc`. `g++` sets the include paths correctly for C++, as well as make sure the correct libraries and runtime is linked with the program.

Comment: OK the problem was that I just added to setup.py sources the swig interface file withouth swig_opts with the -c++ option and so swig was generating a module.c file and gcc compiled it as a C source. so I added `swig_opts=['-c++', '-py3']` and it runs OK :)

Answer (score 6):

`<cmath>` is not a standard C header.  It is a C++ header.  Use `g++` instead of `gcc`.

Answer (score 4):

generally cmath is in c++(g++)'s include path, not gcc.

1. use #include 'math.h' with gcc;  or
2. use #include 'cmath' with g++

You can check the default include path of gcc by

```
echo | gcc -v -E -
```